# Why am I getting error on FROM statement?

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

```
UPDATE a
  SET a.PropertyAddress = COALESCE(a.PropertyAddress,b.PropertyAddress)
    FROM nashvillehousing as a
    JOIN nashvillehousing as b
    ON a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
       WHERE a.UniqueID <> b.UniqueID
       AND a.PropertyAddress is null;
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  This is not standard SQL and won't work in most databases.

Comment: This looks more like SQL-Server syntax than MySQL.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a `FROM` clause in `UPDATE`. You name the first table in the `UPDATE` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's tagged `mysql`

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, the syntax would be:

```
UPDATE nashvillehousing nh JOIN
       nashvillehousing nh2
       ON nh.ParcelID = nh2.ParcelID
    SET nh.PropertyAddress =  nh2.PropertyAddress)
    WHERE nh.UniqueID <> nh2.UniqueID AND
          nh2.PropertyAddress is null;
```

Note the use of *meaningful* table aliases (abbreviations for the table names), rather than arbitrary letters.  Also, the `coalesce()` is not needed, because the `WHERE` clause filters out `NULL` values.